# Functions and inner product spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

If $L$ is a real valued function defined on $\mathbb R^n$, defined as $L(x) = \langle x,y\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is some inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ and $y$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and we denote derivative of $l$ by $DL$. Then which of the following is necessarily true:

(a) $DL(u)=dl(v)$ for all $u,v$ in  $\mathbb R^n$.

(b) $DL(0,0,\dotsc,0)=L$.

(c) $DL(x)=\lVert x\rVert^2$ for all $x$ in  $\mathbb R^n$.

(d) $DL(1,1,\dotsc,1)=0$.

Please, someone give me a hint for how I start to solve this question. If someone know the complete question please tell me. I don't know how to start this question.

Comment: How do you define $dl$?

Comment: And I assume you mean that $l(x)$ is defined by $l(x) = <x,y>$ since it seems to be missing from your question?

Comment: that i do not understand this is a question in an examination

Comment: yes ,sir sorry for that.

Comment: Try for the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. dot product, see which of these it satisfies. It is always helpful to start with some examples that we are familiar with.

Comment: according the standard inner product my ans is option d as then $dl(1,1,..1)=l_{x_1}(1)+l_{x_2}(1)+...l_{x_n}(1)$=0. definitily option b,c are false as $dl(0,0,..0)=l_{x_1}(0)+l_{x_2}(0)+...l_{x_n}(0)$=0.and also option c is not true for all x in  R^n. please tell me whether i am right or not .

Comment: @abc Under standard inner product, $l$ is in fact a linear map. Also, it seems to me that you don't understand what $dl$ is.

Comment: oh please tell what $dl$ is ?

Comment: @secret math please response

Comment: @abc As a map $dl: T\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow T\mathbb{R}$. To make it simple, $dl$ takes in a vector, and gives you a real value. Think about the total differential of a map. Hope you can work it out from here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11054/discussion-between-abc-and-secret-math)

Comment: @SecretMath..here dl is the DL...derivative

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am writing this not as a solution, but mainly to help you understand the concepts here.

---

Now $l: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a real valued function. Its derivative gives again a real valued function $dl: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. To understand it in an easy way, think about the standard inner product, in which case we denote $l = f$ to specify that this is only a special case. Suppose $y = (y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n)$, then

$f(x) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + \cdots + x_ny_n$.

Then $df$ is the total differential

$df = f_{x_1}dx_1 + f_{x_2}dx_2 + \cdots + f_{x_n}dx_n = y_1dx_1 + y_2dx_2 + \cdots + y_ndx_n$.

Now how does $df$ act on a vector? It does the same as $f$, i.e. $df(\vec{v}) = \langle \vec{v}, \vec y\rangle$. Then here it already gives you a lot of information and helps you to understand the map $dl$.

(a) is incorrect, since $df(0, 0, \cdots, 0) = 0$, and $df$ is not constantly zero. (b) is incorrect, as $dl$ is a function, so its value at the point $(0, 0, \cdots, 0)$ cannot be a function, in fact $df(0, 0, \cdots, 0) = 0$. (c) is incorrect, as we have seen that $df(\vec{v}) = \langle \vec{v}, \vec y\rangle \neq \langle \vec{v}, \vec v\rangle = |v|^2$. (d) is incorrect, as $df(1, 1, \cdots, 1) = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i$ not necessarily $0$.

---

To fully understand what is going on here, you need some knowledge about differential geometry. Even in our easy case of standard inner product, things are more complicated than it seems. For example, it is true that $f$ and $df$ do the same thing to a vector, but they are different maps. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $df: T\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow T\mathbb{R}$ is a map between the tangent spaces, but they look the same only because we have the usual identification of $T\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$, i.e. they are both $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces, but with different basis. A very common question is that what we mean by writing the total differential

$df = f_{x_1}dx_1 + f_{x_2}dx_2 + \cdots + f_{x_n}dx_n = y_1dx_1 + y_2dx_2 + \cdots + y_ndx_n$.

and here we are in fact thinking of $dx_i$'s as a basis for the cotangent space $T^*\mathbb{R}^n$, and $df$ is an element in the cotangent space. The vector $\vec v = (v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n)$ actually lives inside the tangent space $T\mathbb{R}^n$, and it represents the element

$v = v_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + v_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} + \cdots + v_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},$

where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$'s is the basis for $T\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

Hopefully it helps you. This might have gone too far for you, but actually it has not gone into very deep concepts yet. If you are in a fundamental level course, then understanding well the example of standard inner would be enough, and if you are in a more advanced level course it is always good to know more.

Comment: @secret Math...first and 2 options are write